# Getting 404 Error when the URI is right

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-studio, zend-server

I am using PHP 5.4, Zend Studio and Zend-Server.

I am getting an 404 error when I use this uri:

```
http://localhost/MyExample/public/index.php
```

but when I use this uri I get the right page to display:

```
http://localhost/MyExample/public/index.php/
```

I would think both of these uri would be the same.

Here is the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is the index.php code:

```
<?php

/**
* This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
* to the application root now.
*/
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Comment: something to do with .htaccess?

Comment: It could be. I am just not sure what.

Comment: could you post relevant code that you have for .htaccess or anything else related to urls eg: php code

Comment: I added the .htaccess file and the php code for php.index

Comment: Seems right in my opinion. There is no route matching `index.php`, so a 404 is thrown. When using `/` or `/index.php/`, the path matched by the router is empty, so you get the `home` route matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: Adding previous comment as answer**

This is the correct behavior. The URI passed to the router when you type `http://localhost/index.php` contains `"index.php"`.

Since there is no route matching `"index.php"`, a 404 error is displayed by Zend Framework 2.

When using `"/"` or `"/index.php/"`, [the path matched by the router is empty](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php#L133-L142), so you get the default `"home"` route of the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) is matched.